# Determine if node was deleted in JTree

Tags: java, swing, jtree

Right now, I have a `TreeSelectionListener` on my `JTree`. This works fine. However, I need to detect the case that a node has been deleted. I am not sure how to do this using a TreeSelectionEvent.

I haven't seen anything in the JavaDoc about it. I was looking for something analogous to a `TableModelEvent` where it has a `getType()` method that allows you to know if something was updated,deleted, or inserted into the table. Any idea how this can be detected?

I can't use a TreeModelListener, because when I call:

```
((DefaultTreeModel)getModel()).removeNodeFromParent(node);
```

On my tree, it triggers the `valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent)` to be fired. This is what I am trying to escape from.

Something like:

```
public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent treeSelectionEvent){
    if(treeSelectionEvent.someMethod()){ <----need this
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> I need to detect the case that a node has been deleted

To detect that a node has been deleted, you can use a [`TreeModelListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/TreeModelListener.html). Simple example:

```
DefaultTreeModel model = new DefaultTreeModel(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root"));
JTree tree = new JTree(model);
model.addTreeModelListener(new TreeModelListener(){
    public  void treeNodesRemoved(TreeModelEvent e){
        //do something
    }
    //further listener implementation here
});
```

**EDIT**: To prevent the Selection listener from firing when deleting the node, you could

1. Remove the selection listener
2. Delete the node
3. add back the selection listener

Comment: Thanks, please see my edit. Maybe there's something I am missing. But my TreeSelection Listener is being called when I remove a node from my model. This is what I am trying to detect and stop.

Comment: Deletion occurs within the model, selection within the view. If you wish to prevent the Listener from firing when deleting a node, then you could a) remove selection listener b) delete the node c) add back the selection listener